# ffmpeg copy and discard missing or incomplete frames

Tags: ffmpeg

If theres a video file that is partially downloaded, how can you use ffmpeg to copy it and cut out all the incomplete and/or corrupt frames.

Tried this:

`ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i video.mkv -c copy video_fixed.mkv`

Source: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18220/fix-bad-files-and-streams-with-ffmpeg-so-vlc-and-other-players-would-not-crash

but it simply copied the video missing / incomplete frames and all.

Comment: You can't. Not in the way you want. Video streams commonly rely on temporal compression, so that most frames require other frame for decoding. So, if a video consists of frames A B C D E and C gets corrupted then C can't be decoded and neither can D & E. You can try re-encoding to see if that helps.

Comment: I don't think thats that's the case. A frame may be based off previous N frames, however there are certain frames (key frame?) that don't depend on previous frames or there is sufficient data from a previous frame to complete the current frame.

For example, in VLC, good frames will be display followed be partially corrupted frames followed by complete frames. I'd like simply to skip all the corrupt frame. Maybe this is a limitation of ffmpeg. Is some other tool better suited for this?